# dalekjs selector ain't working when contains doubledot

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, testing, dalekjs

following situation:

```
Table
  th
    tbody
       tr
         td
         td
         td
       tr
         td
         td
         td //I need this one crucial entry for my test
```

I tried and succeeded to access it on the browser console with this selector:

```
'.tableclasss tbody tr:last td:eq(2)'
```

but this fails if i use it in DalekJS becaus of the colons!

if I use

```
'.tableclasss tbody tr'
```

the selector finds the tablerows but as soon as i use a colon like:

```
'.tableclasss tbody tr:last'
```

the selection fails.

Any known issues about that?

Versions:
Win7
dalek-cli 0.0.4
dalekjs local install: 0.0.8

Comment: Instead of an ASCII art, please show the actual markup you have.

Comment: try $('.tableclasss tbody tr').last().find('td').eq(2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem is that you mistake selectors that work within the jQuery selector engine & selectors that are defined in the CSS spec.

When you write `tr:last` you actually want `tr:last-child` or `.tableclass tr:last-of-type` etc.

Please go check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) MDN page that explains the defined selectors & pseudo selectors, not all are supported by every browser, but most of them do work in modern browsers.

Comment: hey sebastian thanks for explanation. it seems like phantomJS does not support the pseudo selector i needed i also tried it with last-child and last-of element. The problem was solved by asserting the content of the td element within the execute method using jquery!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.last()` and `.eq()` instead:

```
$('.tableclasss tbody tr').last().find('td').eq(2)
```

Comment: hey dude, thanks for response. if i use the mentioned selector .tableclasss tbody tr:last td:eq(2) in jquery it works. i need help in terms of dalekjs. there is obviously an error with the selector handling in the testframework.